# Posting arrays of dictionaries in Swift as JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have two arrays in Swift, a Customer array, and an Order array.

```
 var orders = _orderService.GetOrders(...) //just simplifying
 var customers = _customerService.GetCustomers(...) //simplifying obviously
```

Now that I have these as Array< Order > and Array< Customer >, I'd like to convert them to JSON, and send them in a POST to my web service.

My customer and order classes both have a .toDictionary() implementation that allows them to represent themselves as Dictionary, which is perfect for json!

I am thinking that to properly get them to be represented as JSON in one shot, I can do something like this:

```
  var customerJSON = customers.map({"\(NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject($0.toDictionary(), options: nil, error: &err))"})
```

So this works and produces an array of Strings, with each row in the array being a serialized customer. I can take this same approach for my orders, and can combine them to produce one giant array of strings, each represented as JSON.

What I am stuck on now is what to do with this array to properly POST it.

```
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = <<WHAT GOES HERE TO SEND VALID JSON OVER??>>
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: You should create an NSArray of all your NSDictionarys and serialize that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple like that:

Objective-C:

```
    NSDictionary *data = @{@"orders": orders, @"customers":customers};
    NSData *jsondata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsondata];
```

Swift:

```
  let data = ["orders": orders, "customers":customers]
  let jsondata = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: .allZeros, error: nil)
  request.HTTPBody = jsondata
```